# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estuve practicando y siguiendo un [tutorial de base](https://youtu.be/PmKwlUYEmlc)  sin embargo al momento de hacer la consulta para comprobar usuario me aparece el error "*1046 No database selected*" ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe? comento una solución rápida que encontré sin embargo, siento que no es la adecuada. De igual forma acepto sugerencias para mejorar el código, gracias!

**modulos/Index.php**

```
<?php
echo "Hola soy index en módulos";

if(isset($_POST["login"])){

    include("global/conexion.php");

    $user=($_POST['user']);
    $pass=($_POST['pass']);

    $sentenciaSQL=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbusuarios WHERE username=:username AND password=:password LIMIT 1");//Aqui el error, la solución mas rápida que encontré fue agregar la base de datos, "SELECT * FROM colegio.tbusuarios WHERE username=:username AND password=:password LIMIT 1"

    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam("username",$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam("password",$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute();
    
    $registro=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($registro);

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario']=$registro;
    $numeroregistros=$sentenciaSQL->rowCount();


    if($numeroregistros>=1){
    echo "Bienvenido.....";
    header('Location:template/Vistapanel.php');
    }
    else{
        echo"No hay registros";
    }
}

?>
```

**Global/conexion.php**

```
<?php
 $arrOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

include('config.php');
$servidor="mysql:bdname=".BD.";host=".SERVIDOR;
try{
    $pdo= new PDO($servidor,USUARIO,PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));

    echo"<script> alert('Conectandose....');</script>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo"<script> alert('Error....');</script>";
}
?>
```

Global/config.php

```
<?php
define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
define("USUARIO","root");
define("PASSWORD","");
define("BD","colegio");
?>
```

Comment: Estuve investigando, si agrego la base de datos en la consulta, esta funciona:

$sentenciaSQL=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM colegio.tbusuarios WHERE username=:username AND password=:password LIMIT 1");

Comment: Agregar la base de datos en la consulta funciono para mi también, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un typo, es **dbname** NO **bdname**

```php
$servidor="mysql:bdname=".BD.";host=".SERVIDOR;
```

debería ser

```php
$servidor="mysql:dbname=".BD.";host=".SERVIDOR;
```

Aquí te dejo la documentación del constructor para [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Ahh es verdad! muchas gracias! pensé que era algo relacionado  con la base de datos